# How to use specs for subplots in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I want to create a 2x2 subplot with 3 plots.

The first plot in whole first row (1X2). Second and Third plot, below,

My Code:

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"colspan": 2}, None],
          [{}, {}]],
    subplot_titles=("Patents","Institutions", "Countries"))
```

I get the following error:

```
    ValueError: 
No subplot specified at grid position (1, 2)
```

But the plot in first row second column (1,2) is specified as None, or?

I also tried it with rowspan, but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me, i forgot to specifie the position of each plot in the

```
fig.add_trace(go.xx(), rows=i, cols=k)
```

i.e.

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"colspan": 2}, None],[{}, {}]],
    subplot_titles=("First Subplot","Second Subplot", "Third Subplot"))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=freq),row=1,col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
                 row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
                 row=2, col=2)
```